# Why is my Raspberry Pi 2 with OSMC slow?

Tags: operating-systems, performance

I just installed my new Raspberry Pi 2 B model with the OSMC OS Alpha version 4. While the Pi 2 is supposedly much faster, I experience the device to be not very responsive when navigating the menu's and being very slow in updating the library.

I would like to know how I can find out what causes this slow behavior. Might it be possible that OSMC only uses one of the four cores and is therefore slow? I might try open elec if the device keeps being slow, or reinstall my old pi.

Comment: I have confirmed OSMC on Raspberry Pi 2 is slow. Menu system stops responding, usually after a network setting change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, it seems that the Alpha 4 version of OSMC is not yet stable enough to be run on the Pi 2. I have run into other issues as well, like a black screen at boot where it never loads the GUI itself.

If someone else has problems with OSMC, my advise is to use Open Elec and maybe try again when a beta release of OSMC is ready.

--EDIT--

I tried the stable release of OSMC and things seems to run much beter now. No more slow behavior and a good user experience.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried downloading and re-installing a *fresh* image of OSMC onto the SD card? It could be that there was an error during you burning the OSMC image file onto the SD card therefore OSMC is acting a bit strange.

If that didn't work, my final suggestion is you switch to Open Elec. I know for certain that Open Elec **does fully** support Raspberry Pi 2.

I hope these solutions work for you.

Shayan Doust

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have tried to reinstall OSMC (via the OSMC installer GUI). I guess I should try Open Elec

Comment: I tried Open Elec and it works like a charm.

Comment: I'm glad Open Elec worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like OSMC is now almost final and this topic might be out of date a bit. I tried OSMC and OpenELEC via NOOBS yesterday on Raspberry Pi and OSMC seems to be coming out faster. It's a couple of seconds slower to boot but seems faster once it's up and running. See http://www.htpcbeginner.com/xbian-vs-raspbmc-or-openelec-part1/ for more information

Comment: I agree the topic might be a bit out of date. I have not tested OSMC for a while (and it seems they are distributing release candidates right now). Might give it another try soon. However, your url is not very applicable since it compares xbian, raspbmc and openelec. Raspbmc is the predecessor of OSMC and can not be installed on the Pi 2.